# What would be the security implications of using a CA certificate directly as a server certificate?

Tags: tls

Well, let's imagine that server `S` provides a service to a given set of clients `C1` and `C2` with secured cert-based authentication (think of `OpenVPN`, `SSH` or other similar services).

- `S` could use a trusted CA or create its own to let `C1` and `C2` know that he is the real `S` (what `OpenVPN`, `HTTPS`, etc. do). This requires the CA cert to be pre-shared with each client.
- `S` could just present its certificate to `C1` and `C2` the first time the clients connect to it and the client would check whether this certificate is the one expected (what `SSH`, `Syncthing`, etc. do).

The thing is:

1. Some systems (*cough* android... *cough*) just add the custom CA directly into the global trust store (`OpenVPN`).
2. Also `p12` format is pretty convenient, whereas `pem` is dreadful for the user, yet we often don't have the choice (why are there 4 files? what's the key you were talking about? what's the private cert? why `ca.cert` does not work as my private cert?...).
3. The users *don't like/are not allowed* to validate/type stuff on both server and clients to authenticate each other (`Syncthing`).
4. Yet they can't be bothered to check a certificate hash thoroughly (`SSH`).

A (possibly dreadful) way to solve these problems (and create others) would be to directly use `S` private key to sign `C1` and `C2` certificates:

1. No new CA to add to the system-wide trust store.
2. Only one file to handle in both `p12` and `pem` formats.
3. The user doesn't have to access `S`.
4. The user doesn't have to check anything as long as he can trust the signed certificate given to him (through `HTTPS`/`SSH`, etc.). NB: this trust problem is the same when you have to get the CA cert on each client.

The thing is that I have not heard of such a scheme before. I thinks it is mostly because it does not provide strong improvements over the CA-based scheme, but it could be because the approach is flawed.

So, **are there bad security implications arising from using this kind of scheme?**

PS: I am asking out of curiosity because I don't know any protocol using this scheme, yet it seems a bit simpler.

Comment: This is a "self-signed certificate". They're generally considered a bad thing.

Comment: But in `OpenVPN` for instance, you just don't have a choice... Yes, your server certificate can be signed by a trusted CA, but you can't do that with clients. Of course, I agree with you for one-server-to-many-anonymous-clients connections (e.g. `HTTPS`). But other than that... I mean, `OpenSSH` is not built around trusted CAs and I am not sure it should be.